# Three range query in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have requirement of fetching records using three range queries from cassandra db. I used the following query.

```
Select * from keyspace.test 
         where partitionkey = 'x' 
         and indexedColumn = 'y'
         and column1 < 'value1' 
         and column2 > 'value2' 
         and column3 > 'value3'
```

it failed with following error:

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
>   message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering
>   and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute
>   this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW
>   FILTERING"

Please help if you know how to give three range conditions in single fetch query .

Table Model:

{
id,
childstatus,
startDate,
endDate,
childId
childRatingValue
}(id, childstatus, startdate, childRatingValue)

clustering keys in order (childstatus, startdate, childRatingValue)

index on childstatus

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cassandra is suggesting you to change you data model, because you could run your query, but paying a huge penalty tax. Post your table definition so we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And this is the model:
{
id,
childstatus,
startDate,
endDate,
childId
childRatingValue
}(id, childstatus, startdate, childRatingValue)

clustering keys in order (childstatus, startdate, childRatingValue)
index on childstatus

And the query should fetch all the childids which are matching the following the conditions: id ='123' and childstatus = true and startDate < currentdate and childRatingValue > 5 and enddate > currentdate